# Unity3D Package Conflicts with Package by the Same Name

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, bundle-identifier

I started a new project in Unity3D and imported the assets folder from the project for an app that I previously published to Google Play. I changed the bundle identifier, project name, generated a new keystore, and saved the apk with a new name. However when I try to install the new app on my Android device, I get the Android error message "Package Conflicts with Package by the Same Name" If I uninstall the previous app the new app will install, but the previous app is published and I want users to be able to have both of my apps installed. Any ideas on why this new project with only the assets of an old project still thinks it is the old project?  I did search all text files for the older project's name.

Thanks,
Johnny

Comment: If you use something like aapt to inspect your apk, does the information it prints match what you expect? `aapt l -a mybuild.apk`

Comment: Bart:  Thanks for the question.  I just ran aapt. the old name is not in the results, and the bundle id is what I would expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started a new project new bundle id, name, keystore... and still had the same issue.  Out of desperation I decided to change the Facebook app settings to the new Facebook app.  The conflict has gone away, and both apps can be installed.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: Sorry for the really long delay.  I created a new Facebook app through the Facebook developer web portal.